# how to implement Expandable list item?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I have a list of items displayed with a small image and name. On clicking the list item, a detailed description of the item with image (probably a new layout) should be displayed in the expanded view, while the other list items goes down gradually, giving space for expanded view.  Could some one give me some direction on how to achieve the same?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExpandableProjectsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

   private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
   public LayoutInflater inflater;
   public Activity activity;

   public ExpandableProjectsListAdapter(Activity act, SparseArray<Group> groups) {
      activity = act;
      this.groups = groups;
      inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
   }

   @Override
   public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
      TextView text = null;
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
      }
      text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      text.setText(children);
      convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, children,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      });
      return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
     return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
     return groups.get(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public int getGroupCount() {
     return groups.size();
  }

  @Override
  public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
     super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
     super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
     return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
      }
      Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
      ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(group.string);
      ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
      return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
     return false;
  }

 @Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     return false;
  }
 }
```

And in your fragment, do

```
public class ProjectsFragment extends Fragment {

  Activity activity;
  SparseArray<Group> groups = new SparseArray<Group>();

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity){
     super.onAttach(activity);
     this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_projects, container, false);

      createData();
      ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView)    rootView.findViewById(R.id.projects);
      ExpandableProjectsListAdapter adapter = new ExpandableProjectsListAdapter(activity,
            groups);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      return rootView;
 }

 public void createData() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        Group group = new Group("Project " + j);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            group.children.add("Learn programming using a simple project developing android applications and be guided by a mentor free of charge");
        }
        groups.append(j, group);
    }
   }
  }
```

For your xml layout, you need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/projects"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```